# Can I make string clickable in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some `string`s that I am displaying using material-ui and react:

```
    <Typography paragraph variant="body1">
      {text1}
      <strong>{text2}</strong>
    </Typography>
```

These are populated by DB lookup. How can I make this text clickable if there is a URL in the DB entry (eg text on DB is: 'microsoft: www.microsoft.com'?

Comment: Unfortunately `String` does not have the ability to handle click events in nature, It must be `HTML` tags only so that click events to fire. So instead you can add this string into some other tag and provide a click event on that tag or else you delegate the event and check for the clicked element so that you can perform a function on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Material UI's `Link` component: https://material-ui.com/components/links/

```
<Typography paragraph variant="body1">
  <Link href={url}>
    {text1}
  </Link>
  <strong>{text2}</strong>
</Typography>
```

Comment: Thanks there is no magic way of making `string` clickable then?

Comment: Code isn't magic. The only way to make text clickable is by enclosing it in a component, in this case `Link`. Seeing that not all of your DB entries have a URL, your best shot would be to use regex to determine whether or not a URL exists and to extract it, then use conditional formatting to inject the `Link` component. But I think that warrants another question altogether.